# Laravel on sub domain ignore parent cookies when

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I have a laravel app on a parent domain. `SESSION_DOMAIN` is set to `.domain.com` because I want the cookies to be shared with another subdomain `first.domain.com`.

I now want to publish another app at `second.domain.com` which is separate from `domain.com` and `first.domain.com`.

The `SESSION_DOMAIN` for this second app is correctly set to `second.domain.com`.

Everytime I try to login via sanctum I get an error `CSRF token mismatch`.

I'm pretty certain this is due to the multiple cookies on multiple domains since if I clear my cookies for the parent `domain.com` or use incognito mode or another browser then the issue goes away.

The issue only exists when both `.domain.com` and `second.domain.com` have a XSRF-TOKEN cookie token set.

Everything else seems to work fine, presumably because the other cookie Laravel uses called `_session` is prefixed by the app name and therefore unique.

Where as the `XSRF-TOKEN` is always called `XSRF-TOKEN`.

How can I set it up so that my parent domain can share cookies with `first.domain.com` but doesn't interfere with `second.domain.com`?

Comment: Cookies set for a domain are always accessible on subdomains as well. Only way to prevent that, would be to leave the `domain` portion out of the Set-Cookie header to begin with (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value: _"If omitted, this attribute defaults to the host of the current document URL, not including subdomains."_) - but I am not sure if Laravel allows for that via the configuration, plus you would have to explicitly set a second cookie valid for `first.domain.com` as well here then.

Comment: The other alternative would be that you configure your app under `second.domain.com` to use a different session _name_.

Comment: I don't think the session name has anything to do with it, it's already using a different session name. The name used for the XSRF-TOKEN is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work around that seems to work.

By adding the following to my blade template that is rendering the SPA.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And then when initialising Axios (this is in bootstrap.js in the default Laravel setup) add the crsf-token as a default header.

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
```

This bypasses the cookie, you can see in Laravel's `VerifyCsrfToken` that it checks for this header first (actually second you could also send `_token` as a GET or POST param).

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4ffac6f71467562dbe670f893af787bf5c610103/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L151

The one gotcha i've found is that when you logout of Sanctum you usually want to reset the token.

The best bet would be to return `csrf_token()` in the Logout response and then update the header similar to above.

e.g:

```
/**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'You have been logged out.',
            'csrf_token' => csrf_token()
        ]);
    }
```

```
axios.post('/api/auth/logout').then(response => {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = response.data.csrf_token
})
```

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem!